# What is a good way to make multiple full outer join?

Tags: sql

I'd like to know if anyone would know an elegant and scalable method to full outer join multiple tables, given that I might want to regularly add new tables to the join?

For now my method consists in full joining table A with table B, store the result as a cte, then full joining the cte to table C, store the result as a cte2, full joining cte2 to table D... you got it.

Creating a new cte every time i want to add another table to the join is not very practical, but every other solutions i found so far have the same issue, there's always some kind of infinite looping either on ctes or in selects (like SELECT blabla FROM (SELECT blabla2 FROM..)).

Is there any way that i don't know that would help me perform this multiple full join without falling in an infinite recursive loop of ctes?

Thanks

EDIT: Sorry it seems it wasn't clear enough
When i perform a multiple full join in one query like:

```
SELECT
    a.*, b.*, c.*
FROM
    tableA a
FULL JOIN
    tableB b
ON
    a.id = b.id
FULL JOIN
    tableC c
ON
    a.id = c.id
```

If the id is present in tableB and tableC but not tableA, my result will create two lines where there should be one, because i joined b to a and c to a but not b to c. That's why i need to full join the result of the full join of a and b to c.
So if i have let's say five table instead of three, i need to full join the result of the full join of the result of the full join of the result of the full join... x)

Comment: It's not clear why the answer isn't just `FULL OUTER JOIN` multiple times in a single `FROM` clause, no CTEs, etc. Perhaps you could expand the example to make clear why that's not what you need?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=18fc9726120ed685c70903302243827f) illustrates the problem.

If you want the rows from tables B and C to join, you need to accomodate the fact that maybe the data comes from table B and not A. The easiest is probably to use `COALESCE`.

Your join should therefore look like:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*
FROM tableA a
FULL JOIN tableB b ON a.id = b.id
FULL JOIN tableC c ON COALESCE(a.id, b.id) = c.id
-- FULL JOIN tableD d ON COALESCE(a.id, b.id, c.id) = d.id
-- FULL JOIN tableE e ON COALESCE(a.id, b.id, c.id, d.id) = e.id
```

Comment: "This would mean that a.id is NULL, which would prevent tableC from joining."
It's a full join, if a.id is null on an x value, but both B and C have an id corresponding to that x value, it creates two rows

Comment: Oh indeed, sorry, I had a brain lag it seems :-) My answer solves this problem. I'll update the introduction accordingly.

Comment: The solution itself works though, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Most databases that support `FULL JOIN` also support `USING`, which is the simplest way to do what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA a FULL JOIN
     tableB b
     USING (id) FULL JOIN
     tableC c
     USING (id);
```

The semantics of `USING` mean that only non-`NULL` values are used, if such a value is available.